# How to turn a zend helper to a singleton?

Tags: php, zend-framework, singleton, helper, zend-view

I need to use a view helper to make counts in a bunch of different partials.
In the partials I can't access view variables, but I can access helpers, so I created this simple class.

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Counter extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract{
    protected $count = 0;
    public function counter(){
        return $this;
    }
    public function add($i = 1){
        $this->count = $this->count + (int) $i;
        return $this;   
    }
    public function get(){
        return $this->count;    
    }
    public function set($count){
        $this->count  = (int) $count;
        return $this;   
    }
}
```

However this `<?php echo $this->counter()->add()->get()?>` Always returns 1. I guess this is because it's always a different instance of the class. How would I need to change the `counter()` function so that it can count through all the views and partials?

Comment: Don't use another singleton for this. You may use bootstrap params or Zend Registry object to store the counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use statics:

   ```
   static protected $count = 0;
   public function add($i = 1){
     self::$count = self::$count + (int) $i;
     return $this;   
   }
   ```
2. Write a separate counter singleton and then do:

   ```
    public function get(){
      return Counter::getInstance();
    }
    public function add($i = 1){
       Counter::getInstance()->add($i);
       return $this;
    }
   ```

If you want, you may also extend it by using named counters and then $count would be an array.

Comment: 2 does the same as 1 by using separate singleton class - see here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php